# Calculating unbiased survival rate of Titanic passengers

Tags: descriptive-statistics, odds-ratio, likelihood-ratio, ratio

I want to calculate unbiased ratio of the survival chance of the passengers according to the classes(1st,2nd,3rd class)- so passengers from which class had higher chance to survive.

So let's say in the data we have number of passengers  survived and the total number of passengers(per class). So how should i calculate the ratio to be unbiased? I was told that dividing the number of survivors by total passengers in that class was biased since there were much less 1st class passengers so they could easily fit into the rescue boats.

So i was told to calculate the total number of survivors and assume that this is the amount of available seats in the rescue boats. Then i divide the number of survivors for each class by this new total number. Is it the correct way of doing that? Is there a better way?

The data is here if needed:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Biased, since they could easily fit into the rescue boats.

Biased in terms of them surviving, yes. However, it will not cause any bias in terms of your estimates. It may cause lower confidence due to smaller sample size, however. This may have been what they were referring to.

Think about it logically. If we removed the circumstances that gave the higher class a greater chance to survive, we'd end up with every single class having approximately the same survival rate. If we want useful statistics, we need to factor in the advantages of the higher class. This method of using total survivors as available seats assumes that all passengers had equal access to all rescue boats. I would assume that higher class passengers would have greater access to safety due to purchasing premium tickets, and therefore we shouldn't combine these samples.

EDIT: In reference to:

> Divide the number of survivors for each class by [total number of survivors].

This result will simply just tell you what proportions of survivors were which class (e.g 10% higher, 40% middle, 50% lower). Since we're calculating survival chance per class, using these values is meaningless, since the percentage of survivors that were [x class] is heavily dependent on the number of passengers that were in [x class].

For example, if 50 out of 50 higher class passengers survived, but there were 10,000 people on board and 5,000 were rescued, higher class would make up 1% of all survivors despite having a 100% survival rate.